# Why am I not be able to keep blank in case statement in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN '' AND CS.START <> '99' THEN 'CSE'
        WHEN '' AND CS.START = '99'  THEN 'ECE'
        WHEN '' AND CS.START <> '99' THEN 'CIVIL_E' 
    END AS STREAM
FROM
    C_STREAM CS
```

I'm getting an error

> ORA-00920: INVALID RELATIONAL OPERATOR

Comment: When what is ''?  The query needs something to compare '' with?  Are you meant to be saying WHEN CS.START <> '' AND CS.START <> '99', etc. ..... You can only say something like WHEN '' on its own if you have a field name (or variable) after the word CASE to compare with - for example: SELECT CASE CS.START WHEN '' .... THEN - that is acceptable, because you are specifying what should be compared with the '' (empty string)

Comment: Except in Oracle `''` isn't treated as an empty string, it's equivalent to `null` - so you would need to do `CASE WHEN some_column IS NULL ...`. (You can't use the simple case form `CASE some_column WHEN NULL ...` here - it doesn't work with null comparison.)

Comment: This doesn't make a great deal of sense. Your first and third conditions appear identical, which means only the first one would ever match. It would help a lot if you *explained* what you were trying to do and supplied some sample data and expected results, rather than expecting us to *divine* your intentions from broken code.

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I not be able to keep blank in case statement in Oracle SQL?

The `WHEN` clause of a (searched) `CASE` statement expects a Boolean expression.

`''` is not a Boolean expression, it is a string literal (and `''` is the same as `NULL`) so you are not able to use it because the syntax does not allow you to.

You would want:

```sql
CASE 
WHEN '' IS NULL AND CS.START <> '99' THEN 'CSE'
WHEN '' IS NULL AND CS.START = '99'  THEN 'ECE'
WHEN '' IS NULL AND CS.START <> '99' THEN 'CIVIL_E' 
END AS STREAM
```

or you could use another relational operator such as `=`, `<>`, `LIKE`, etc. (however, since `''` is identical to `NULL` then using another relational operator to `IS NULL` would mean the result of the expression is never true as `NULL` is never equal or not-equal to anything else, even another `NULL`).

---

The syntax for a [`CASE` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CASE-statement.html#GUID-F4251A23-0284-4990-A156-00A92F83BC35) is:

> #### `searched_case_statement ::=`
>
> [image: searched case statement syntax diagram]

And then the syntax for a [Boolean expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/expression.html#GUID-D4700B45-F2C8-443E-AEE7-2BD20FFD45B8) is:

> #### `boolean_expression ::=`
>
> [image: Boolean expression syntax diagram]
>
> #### `boolean_literal ::=`
>
> [image: Boolean literal syntax diagram]
>
> #### `other_boolean_form ::=`
>
> [image: Other boolean form syntax diagram]

> #### Semantics
>
> ##### `boolean_expression`
>
> Expression whose value is `TRUE`, `FALSE`, or `NULL`. For more information, see "BOOLEAN Expressions".
>
> ##### Restriction on `boolean_expression`
>
> Because SQL has no data type equivalent to `BOOLEAN`, you cannot:
>
> - [...]
> - Use a `BOOLEAN` expression in a SQL statement, except as an argument to a PL/SQL function invoked in a SQL query, or in a PL/SQL anonymous block.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be missing the name of the column you want to check for `''`.

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN "COLUMN" = '' AND CS.START <> '99' THEN 'CSE'
        WHEN "COLUMN" = '' AND CS.START = '99'  THEN 'ECE'
        WHEN "COLUMN" = '' AND CS.START <> '99' THEN 'CIVIL_E' 
    END AS STREAM
FROM
    C_STREAM CS
```

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion but I already tried this and got error like "COLUMN" : invalid identifier